# Python Type Error a float is required

Tags: python, python-2.7, float

Quando vou printar os métodos c1.getTotalDescontos() e c1.getSalarioLiquido() por algum motivo o python esta exigindo uma conversão para float, esses métodos sempre retornam int ou float, não consigo imaginar o motivo para essa conversão.

Já tentei usar float() no retorno dos métodos e dentro do print porém o erro continua, se eu utilizo o .format no print o programa roda com essa mensagem no lugar das variaveis:

```py
Total dos Descontos: <bound method calcPagamento.__calcularTotalDescontos of <__main__.calcPagamento object at 0x7f1574d18b00>
>                                                                                                                             
Sálario Líquido: <bound method calcPagamento.__calcularSalarioLiquido of <__main__.calcPagamento object at 0x7f1574d18b00>>
```

O engraçado que o método praticamente idêntico c1.getSalarioBruto() funciona sem nenhum problema. Gostaria de entender o que está acontecendo.

```py
class calcPagamento:
__salarioBruto = 0
__sindicato = 0
__fgts = 0
__ir = 0
__totalDescontos = 0.0
__salarioLiquido = 0.0



def calcularPagamento(self, pagamentoHora, horasTrabalhadas):
    try:
        self.__salarioBruto = self.__calcularSalarioBruto(pagamentoHora, horasTrabalhadas)
        self.__sindicato, self.__fgts, self.__ir = self.__calcularImpostos(self.__salarioBruto)
        self.__totalDescontos = self.__calcularTotalDescontos
        self.__salarioLiquido = self.__calcularSalarioLiquido
        return True
    except ValueError:
        print('Caught this error: ' + repr(ValueError))
        return False


def getSalarioBruto(self):
    return self.__salarioBruto

def getFgts(self):
    return self.__fgts

def getSindicato(self):
    return self.__sindicato

def getIr(self):
    return self.__ir

def getTotalDescontos(self):
    return self.__totalDescontos

def getSalarioLiquido(self):
    return self.__salarioLiquido

def __calcularSalarioBruto(self, pagamentoHora, horasTrabalhadas):
    if pagamentoHora < 0 or horasTrabalhadas < 0:
        raise ValueError("O Salário Bruto não pode ser negativo!")
    else:    
        return pagamentoHora * horasTrabalhadas

def __calcularImpostos(self, salarioBruto):
    sindicato = salarioBruto * 0.03
    fgts = salarioBruto * 0.11

    if salarioBruto < 900:
        ir = 0
    elif salarioBruto >= 900 and salarioBruto < 1500:
        ir = 0.05
    elif salarioBruto >= 1500 and salarioBruto < 2500:
        ir = 0.1
    else:
        ir = 0.2

    return sindicato, fgts, ir

def __calcularSalarioLiquido(self, salarioBruto, impostos):
    salarioLiquido = salarioBruto

    for x in range(0, len(impostos)):
        salarioLiquido = salarioLiquido - descontos[0]

    return salarioLiquido

def __calcularTotalDescontos(self, salarioBruto, impostos):

    for x in range(0, len(impostos)):
        descontos[x] = salarioBruto - salarioBruto * impostos[x]
        totalDescontos += descontos[x]
    return totalDescontos
```

main:

```py
valorHora = float(input("Informe o valor da hora trabalhada: "))
horasMes = int(input("Informe a quantidade de horas trabalhadas no mês: "))

c1 = calcPagamento()

if c1.calcularPagamento(valorHora, horasMes):

    print("Salário Bruto: %.2f" % c1.getSalarioBruto())
    print("Sindicato: {0:.1f}%".format(c1.getSindicato()))
    print("FGTS: {0:.1f}%".format(c1.getFgts()))
    print("Imposto de Renda: {0:.1f}%".format(c1.getIr()))
    print("Total dos Descontos: %.2f" % c1.getTotalDescontos())
    print("Sálario Líquido: %.2f" % c1.getSalarioLiquido())
else:
    print("falhou")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na linha 16 não há o parentese no metodo

```
#Incorreto:
self.__totalDescontos = self.__calcularTotalDescontos
```

```
#correto
self.__totalImpostos = self.__sindicato + self.__fgts + self.__ir #Só adicionei essa linha pra ficar mais legivel
self.__totalDescontos = self.__calcularTotalDescontos(self.__salarioBruto, self.__totalImpostos )
```

da primeira forma vc está passando a referencia da função para o self.__totalDescontos e assim transformando ele em uma função tambem:

```
self.__totalDescontos = self.__calcularTotalDescontos

print(self.__calcularTotalDescontos(self.__salarioBruto, self.__totalImpostos ) == self.__totalDescontos(self.__salarioBruto, self.__totalImpostos ))
```

Outra coisa! Ao invés de vc usar os "gets" (getSalarioBruto(), etc) vc pode simplesmente colocar o decorador @property na função e chamá-la como método:

```
class calcPagamento:

    __salarioBruto = 7

    @property
    def salarioBruto(self):
        return self.__salarioBruto

c1 = calcPagamento()

print(c1.salarioBruto)
```

Comment: Erro infantil mesmo, coisa de gente cega, passar de linguagem tipada para não tipada é bem problemático. Resolveu meu problema, se quiser deixar sua resposta mais completa explique a diferença entre os getters/setters com o @property linkando um post